# Not sure about instance variable scenario in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Here's the class (ignore the console.logs which are left over from my attempt to debug)

```
import fs = require('fs');

export interface Answer {
  order: number,
  text: string
}

export class Config {
  answers:Answer[];
  timestamp_column: string;
  name_column: string

  fromJSONFile(fileName: string) {
    var fileString = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
    this.answers = JSON.parse(fileString.toString());
    console.log(this.answers);
  }

  mapAnswerToNum(answer:string):number {
    console.log(typeof this.answers);
    for (var a in this.answers) {
      if (a.text == answer) { return a.order;}
    }
    for (var a in this.answers) {
      console.log(a.text);
    }
    console.log(typeof this.answers);
    throw new Error(`Invalid response string ${answer}`);
  }
}
```

And here's the invocation:

```
import { Config } from './config';

var config = new Config();
config.fromJSONFile("./csvconfig.json");

...

var respInts:number[] = respStrings.map(this.config.mapAnswerToNum);

...
```

The question: inside the body of mapAnswerToNum, it seems like `this.answers` is undefined, even though in the body of `fromJSONFile` it *is* defined.

Am I being hosed by `this`? What's the right way to code my intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mapAnswerToNum` is defined on `Config`'s prototype, the function being passed to `map` is the function that is shared across all instances of `Config`. So in this case, the context is being lost.

You can fix this by changing the code to the following:

```
var respInts:number[] = respStrings.map((respString) => this.config.mapAnswerToNum(respString));
```

That will call `mapAnswerToNum` on `this.config`'s instance.

---

Here's an example:

```
class Config {
    mapAnswerToNum() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
var Config = (function () {
    function Config() {
    }
    Config.prototype.mapAnswerToNum = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };
    return Config;
})();
```

So when using it:

```
function dummyArrayMap(func) {
    func();
}

var config = new Config();

// logs window since this function is shared across all instances of `Config`.
dummyArrayMap(config.mapAnswerToNum); // the context is lost.
// logs the instance of config since we called the function on the instance
dummyArrayMap(() => config.mapAnswerToNum());
```

---

Alternative to all this, you could use an arrow function on `mapAnswerToNum`. This isn't a solution I like because then the function is no longer on the prototype. I'll demonstrate it with the example above:

```
class Config {
    mapAnswerToNum = () => {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
var Config = (function () {
    function Config() {
        var _this = this; // notice this is saved here
        this.mapAnswerToNum = function () {
            console.log(_this); // then used here
        };
    }
    return Config;
})();
```

So when using it:

```
var config = new Config();

dummyArrayMap(config.mapAnswerToNum);         // logs config
dummyArrayMap(() => config.mapAnswerToNum()); // logs config
```

Comment: Interesting...Help me learn better: What is 's' in your expression? Also, what does it matter that *the function being passed to map is the function that is shared across all instances of Config.*? In my code, what would the value of 'this' be inside of the execution of mapAnswerToNum?

Comment: 1. `s` is a `respString`. It's standard to use a single letter in a short expression like this, but you could replace it with `respString`, which I have gone ahead and done. 2. It matters that the same function is being shared across all instances because that function isn't bound to a specific instance and so when you reference that function without it being called on a specific instance the context will be lost. 3. You can find out the value of `this` by doing `console.log(this);` or by debugging and checking (it should be `Window`)

Comment: Fantastic, David, thanks a lot! Let me try to state what I think I learned: When I call this.method name, this. tells me what instance's prototype has the function, but when that function is called, the `this` inside the body is not automatically equal to the '`this` of the invocation. Hmm. Makes we wonder for now, if that is true, how *is* this `this` inside the invocation determined? (I am running under `node` for example.)